# How to group rows based on multiple fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a `notifications` table where I email out reports to people based on the frequency they've selected.

If an email address exists across multiple `questions` and has the same `frequency`...then I need to group them together so I can send one report for both questions.

```
[
   #<Notification id: 1, question_id: 58, email: "john@example.com", frequency: "daily">, 
   #<Notification id: 2, question_id: 25, email: "john@example.com", frequency: "daily">,
   #<Notification id: 3, question_id: 47, email: "john@example.com", frequency: "monthly">,
   #<Notification id: 3, question_id: 19, email: "frank@example.org", frequency: "monthly">
]
```

So in my example data, 3 reports would be sent:

- 1 to john@example.com for question's 58 and 25 on a daily basis
- 1 to john@example.com for question 47 on a monthly basis
- 1 to frank@example.org for question 19 on a monthly basis

I may not be explaining this very well, so let me know if something needs clarification.

Comment: how does `notification` fit with your other models?

Comment: Question has_many Notifications and Notification belongs_to Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a regular group_by:

```
@notifications = your_method_to_retrieve_notifications
@notifications = @noticications.group_by do |notif|
  notif.ferquency + ':' + notif.email
end
```

This will group your notifications like this:

```
@notifications = {
  'daily:john@example.com' => [<Notification id: 1>, #etc.],
  'monthly:john@example.com' => [# list of notifications],
  'monthly:frank@example.org' => [# list of notif]
}
```

---

If you want only an array of list of notifications grouped by frequency & email, use the above method and add this:

```
@notifications = your_method_to_retrieve_notifications
@notifications = @noticications.group_by do |notif|
  notif.ferquency + ':' + notif.email
end.values
# returns Array of arrays like:
[
  [<Notification id: 1 frequency: "daily", email "a@b.com">,<Notification id: 2 frequency: "daily", email "a@b.com">],
  [<Notification id: 3 frequency: "daily", email "xx@yy.com">],
  [<Notification id: 4 frequency: "monthly", email "a@b.com">,<Notification id: 5 frequency: "monthly", email "a@b.com">],
]
```